# Why does memo.Lines use TStrings instead of TStringList?

Tags: delphi, tstringlist, memo

Why does `Memo.Lines` use the abstract class `TStrings`? Why doesn't it use `TStringList` instead?

And should I convert it to `TStringList` before working with it?

Comment: `TMemo.Lines is TStringList = False`. In fact the actual object that is behind this is a wrapper around the Windows API. The storage is organised by the Windows EDIT control that implements `TMemo`. "Should I convert it to TStringList before working with it?" No. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: TStrings is a lesser "contract" allowing greater flexibility for the developer. You can interact with any class that implements the TStrings abstract class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`TMemo.Lines`, `TListBox.Items`, `TComboBox.Items`, etc. ; all are declared as `TStrings`. Beware, talking about the property that is! The internal created types are `TMemoStrings`, `TListBoxStrings` and `TComboBoxStrings` respectively, which are all descendants of `TStrings` and differ all in way of storage.

And why? For interchangeability and interoperability. So every `TStrings`-descendant has the same properties, and so you can do:

```
Memo1.Lines := ListBox1.Items;
```

How to use? Well, a `TStrings` property like `TMemo.Lines` works just fine. You can add, delete, change, renew and clear the strings (and objects) on the property, because internally it is a `TMemoStrings` which implements all this interaction. Declaration <> implementation.

But when you want any special handling, e.g. like sorting which `TStringList` provides, then you need help. You cannot typecast nor convert a `TMemo.Lines` to a `TStringList`, because it isn't one, but instead you need to create an intermediate object for this special processing:

```
var
  Temp: TStringList;
begin
  Temp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Temp.Assign(Memo1.Lines);
    Temp.Sort;
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(Temp);
  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. So I guess e.g. Memo.Lines.Delete(0) works because it doesn't internally use TStrings?

Comment: Yes. When dropping a memo component on your form doesn't result in an _abstract compiler error_, let's then assume that there is no abstract object being instantiated. ;)

Comment: Surely there's a slicker way to sort in-place.

Comment: Calling `Memo.Lines.Delete()` delegates to the appropriate Win32 API call that actually deletes a line from the UI control.  The APIs are different for different controls, that is why they use different TStrings-derived classes.  That is the beauty of using an abstraction layer like `TStrings`. The caller doesn't have to care HOW it is implemented internally.